# Voltage which produces eddy current

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism

Here is a transformer where we can see the eddy currents in the core:

[image]

I would like to estimate the voltage which induces the eddy currents. I know what voltage is applied to the primary and how much time this voltage is applied. The number of turns on the primary is 1,so I am able to determine what the variation of the flux is.

How can I estimate the voltage into the core as there is no winding, ie no turn?

-------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------

[image]

[image]

Comment: When using Maxwell's equations to find induced emf from rate of change of flux, the loop imagined need not be a physical winding; it can be any imagined, closed loop. See the [integral form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) labelled Faradays law. The eddis form in different sizes, so the voltage causing each eddy will be different.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) Not simple to estimate. If I consider the biggest section of my transformer and highest variation of the flux. I will be able to get the highest voltage ?

Comment: But what do you want to do with that information ? The phrase "*voltage into the core*" is not clear to me. Perhaps you can detail why you need to calculate this value.

Comment: Indeed it is not clear ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to estimate the voltage which induces the eddy currents.

Suppose the total flux through the core of the transformer is given by some function of time \$\Phi(t)\$. Suppose there are N equally sized laminations in the core. We can call the flux through any single lamination \$\phi(t)\$. Assuming that the flux is evenly distributed through the laminations,

$$\phi(t) = \frac{\Phi(t)}{N}$$

There current in a lamination will not be uniform, but will depend upon the loop for that current, and the amount of (changing) flux linked by that loop. The loop with the *largest* amount of linked flux will be the loop that follows the surface of the lamination. That loop will link *all* the flux in the lamination.

The emf of that loop will simply be

$$ V = -\frac{d\phi}{dt}$$

The average emf of the current loops in a lamination will obviously be lower.

Comment: A good answer to an unusual question. Usually, it is sufficient to know the expression to compute the losses generated in the form of heat.